# How to require socketstream in client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, socketstream

I'm using node.js with socketstream while calling server side function.I'm getting 'ss is not defined error'.Can i require that socketstream.how can i require the socketstream.

```
      ss.rpc('User.saveUserInfo',name,pwd,function(res){

      alert(res);

         });
```

Comment: Hi, do you have the 'ss' variable available in your browser console? If not, check that you app.html file includes the <socketstream/> tag, or != socketstream if you're using the jade equivalent.

Comment: @paulbjensen:i didn't include that <socketstream/> tag..now i added that.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue was that the  html tag was not included in the html file's head section.